# Cannot get / Error Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi guys can you please tell the error.
Error

Cannot GET /

all files is in the same directory

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.use('/index', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './index.html'));
});

app.use('/app.js', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './app.js'));
});

app.use('/style.css', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './style.css'));
});

app.listen(8080, function(err){
    if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: There is no GET handler for `/` in your code. That's why you get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wildcards in your route to allow serving multiple files via the same route:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    let filePath = req.params[0] || 'index.html';
    console.log('Getting ' + filePath);
    res.sendFile(filePath, {root: './'});
});

app.listen(8080, function(err){
    if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

It might be better (As others have suggested) to use the static module for this, e.g.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('./'));

app.listen(8080, function(err){
    if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `app.use('/app'` to tell it what to do if a client requests `/app`, and you have `app.use('/app.js'` to tell it what to do if a client requests `/app.js`, and so on.

You don't have `app.use('/'`! So where is it supposed to find `/`?

(NB: For serving up static files, you should probably look at the Express Static module).